# Java SSLSockets and repetition attack

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp

I'm currently working on a Java server platform for a school project. I'm using SSL TCP Sockets  to do the communication and I'm in the stage of developing the JSon protocol between client and server.

My question is whether the messages in the protocol should contain a unique id or if using if the SSL TCP Sockets will be enough to avoid repetition attacks.

Comment: "Should" you do more to secure communication if SSL is compromised?  That's a requirements question.  What is your level of paranoia and confidentiality?  Also "replay attack" is a more common term than "repetition," you might be able to learn more by googling that in stead.  (Also, 'adding a unique ID' doesn't mean much without knowing what you intend to do with it..!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SSL is immune to replay attacks

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are referring to [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), and it might depend on the implementation of your protocol.

If you were to receive the same message twice, how would you handle it?

Imagine Bob sends you a valid, legitimate message. You respond with a valid, legitimate response. SSL protects the channel throughout the conversation, so no one can eavesdrop on the network traffic and see the original request and/or response.

Now imagine I have breached Bob's network and get a copy of the encrypted traffic headed out. If I resend the encrypted message, what would happen? Chances are, SSL would be able to protect me at a later date, since the SSL session would no longer be valid.

But what if I resent the message right away, before the SSL session expired? Would you be susceptible then?

Or does part of your protocol issue a token that I could get a hold of (possibly by shoulder surfing or infecting Bob's computer)? Could I use that token again, possibly from somewhere else, and pretend I was Bob? What is your exposure then?

You just have to walk through the scenarios in your particular case and examine the risk of it happening and the effort to protect it.

In general, SSL protects the channel (data in flight), but you have to design your protocol to be safe at the ends. Including a random token in the protocol (and ensuring it is there) is an easy way to protect against a bunch of different attacks, including replay attacks (think [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) tokens).

Comment: This is barely an answer at all, mostly questions, but the final assertion at the end isn't correct. You don't have to design your protocol against replays over SSL.

Comment: Just because your transport isn't susceptible to replay attacks doesn't mean your protocol isn't. It all depends on where your messages can be injected or replayed.